# Contact form 7 date picker time format

Tags: wordpress, datepicker

I using contact form 7 datepicker plugin and using AM and PM options. Time is not changing after 12 to 1pm it is going 12 to 13. Below is the shortcode which I am using. I want Hour change into 1 PM instead of 13 or 14.

`[datetime appointmentdate date-format:mm/dd/yy time-format:HH:mm_TT min-date:0 min-hour:09 max-hour:17 first-day:1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

[datetime appointmentdate date-format:mm/dd/yy time-format:hh:mm_TT min-date:0 min-hour:09 max-hour:17 first-day:1]

Comment: Thanks masa, it Worked

Comment: As of writing this that solution doesnt work im afraid

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I know this is old but if it helps here is what I had to do.  Just make sure this line is in your theme's function.php file

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' );
```